# Index on multi-field object in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection generated by a map reduce call, and the key is composed by two fields, so my id is set as follow :

```
{
   "_id": {
     "ts": ISODate("2014-04-22T13: 46: 00.0Z"),
     "own": "LP2" 
  }
  //... my fields
}
```

An index is automatically constructed on "_id" :

```
{
   "v": NumberInt(1),
   "key": {
     "_id": NumberInt(1) 
  },
   "ns": "DB.COLLECTION_NAME",
   "name": "_id_" 
}
```

But when I do my queries I often want to sort on "ts" field.

I know that I can construct an index on it, but I was wondering if the index on "_id" was already supporting it, like a compound index. That could save time on insertion.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it will. The way to test this is to insert some test data and try a few test queries. When I ran `db.collectionname.find({}).sort({"_id.ts":-1}).explain()` it was clear that it was not using an index for the sort:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 13,
    "nscannedObjects" : 13,
    "nscanned" : 13,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 13,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 13,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "server" : "local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Note that scanandorder is true.

After adding a new index however that indexed _id.ts directly I saw better results:

```
db.collectionname.ensureIndex({"_id.ts":1})
db.collectionname.find({}).sort({"_id.ts":-1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id.ts_1 reverse",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 13,
    "nscannedObjects" : 13,
    "nscanned" : 13,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 13,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 13,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id.ts" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Note that scanandorder is now false.